# How to create a DAX calculated column in PowerBi that finds the MIN value based on another columns FIRSTDATE?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Need some help to calculate the following in two separate columns in a DAX formula

- Earliest Reading for each equip
- Latest Reading for each equip

[Screenshot of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDrAC.png)

I've been able to get the first date of each equip with this.

```
CALCULATE(FIRSTDATE(Transactions[Date]),ALLEXCEPT(Transactions,Transactions[Equip No]))
```

But cannot work out how to get the 'Reading' value that is associated with the first date

I've managed to do this with a measure, but would also like to get this in a calc. column.

```
Latest Reading = 
SUMX (
    VALUES( Transactions[Equip No] ),
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( Transactions[Reading] ), FIRSTDATE ( Transactions[Date] ) )
)
```

Comment: Consider rewording your Question line as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you.

Earliest Column

```
Earliest = 
VAR __equipNumber = 'Transaction'[Equip No] //Get the Equip No to filter the main table and create an auxiliar table for every different Equip No.
VAR __minDate = CALCULATE( MIN('Transaction'[Date]), FILTER( 'Transaction', 'Transaction'[Equip No] = __equipNumber ) ) //Get the lowest date asociated to every Equip No.
VAR __subTable = FILTER( 'Transaction', 'Transaction'[Date] = __minDate ) //Create a table that contains 1 row asociate to the lowest date.
Return CALCULATE(SUM('Transaction'[Reading]), __subTable) //Operate over the auxiliar table to get the expected value.
```

Latest Column

```
Latest = 
VAR __equipNumber = 'Transaction'[Equip No]
VAR __maxDate = CALCULATE( MAX('Transaction'[Date]), FILTER( 'Transaction', 'Transaction'[Equip No] = __equipNumber ) )
VAR __subTable = FILTER( 'Transaction', 'Transaction'[Date] = __maxDate )
Return CALCULATE(SUM('Transaction'[Reading]), __subTable)
```

I obtained the expected result

[image]

Comment: I managed to get this to work on my test dataset, thank you very much. However, I couldn't get it to work when I added it to my main dataset (has more fields that may be affecting the result). Both earliest and latest columns were just summing up every value in the 'reading' column (irrespective of equip no). Is there anyway you could break down each variable and tell me what exactly is happening so I can debug further.

Comment: I added some comments to my answer so you can check it. What i recommend you to verify is the amount of rows that __subTable var returns. It should return 1 for all cases. You cal also try different functions in the return statement. Instead of SUM you can try using MIN, MAX, DISTINCT. Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the help. I have another scenario where I want to find the Earliest, but have it restricted by a certain date range. For example. I want to see the earliest minimum between 01/03/2020 to 30/30/2020.

Comment: I will asume that the range is between 01/03/2020 and 30/03/2020. The range change depending on all your values or you want to create a column just to that range?

Comment: A column just to that range

Comment: Create a new column and then add these 2 variables:
VAR __startRange = DATE(2020; 03; 01)
VAR __endRange = DATE(2020; 03; 30)   
Then modify __minDate var with this: VAR __minDate = CALCULATE( MIN('Transaction'[Date]); FILTER( 'Transaction'; AND('Transaction'[Equip No] = __equipNumber; AND('Transaction'[Date] >= __startRange; 'Transaction'[Date] <= __endRange  ) ) ) )   
That should gives you the values for the expected range.

Comment: Also  If you only want to show the earliest only in the range rows, replace the return with this: Return  IF( 'Transaction'[Date] >= __startRange && 'Transaction'[Date] <= __endRange; CALCULATE(MIN('Transaction'[Reading]); __subTable) ; BLANK() )